# Variable naming

Tags: python, variables, naming-conventions, naming

**This is not important, only waste your time if you're bored!**

So I'll start like any other question: I'm not that new to programming. In fact I have tried it several times and was victim of tutorial purgatory and too much project based learning with too little knowledge. I'm trying again with python.
I have a question about variable naming because I want to build good habits. I built a program that unzipps files in one directory and puts them in another one. In that directory a folder named after the zip file is created and the content is being put into that. The variable is called folder_directory in the code. folder_directory could literally be anything.
I really thought about it and I can't come up with a name. Here is some of the code:

```
zip_dir = config['DEFAULT']['Where_you_put_your_zipped_files']
unzip_dir = config['DEFAULT']['Where_they_go_after_unzipping']
extension = ".zip"
os.chdir(zip_dir) # change directory from working dir to dir with files

def unzipall():#unzips all the items in zip_dir
    for item in os.listdir(zip_dir): # loop through items in dir
        if item.endswith(extension): # check for ".zip" extension
            file_path = os.path.abspath(item) # get full path of files
            file_name = os.path.basename(os.path.splitext(file_path)[0])#removing the .zip extension and the path to the .zip file, so file_name is just the name of the folder
            folder_directory = unzip_dir + '\\' + file_name + '\\' #creating the name of the aim directory
            createFolder(folder_directory)#create a subfolder that is named after the zip file
            zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(file_path)
            zip_ref.extractall(folder_directory) # extract file to dir
            zip_ref.close() # close file
            os.remove(file_path) # delete zipped file
```

I have a watchdog running and an .ini file to config your dirs just if someone's interested.
So that's my 'problem',
Finn

P.S.: I'm using capital case,camel case and snake case without any logic behind. I should leave that habit behind and become a better person ;-)

Comment: What's your question in short?

Comment: How I should name one variable, which in the code is named folder_directory

Comment: you can name it `path`.

Comment: Thats a good one. Thank you